# I just want the distance value from the function

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi4, pigpio

I just want the distance value from the function, if i print the working_odo it drives me in the while loop. I just want distance

```
def working_odo(): 
    last_state=IO.input(15)
    state_count=0
    while 1:
        current_state=IO.input(15)
        if(current_state!=last_state):
            state_count+=1
            #print(state_count)
            last_state=current_state
            distance = 0.001*state_count
```

This is a raspberry gpio code for encoder

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that got you correctly, maybe:

```
def working_odo(): 
   # YOUR implementation here
   while ... :
       if (current_state != ... :
           return distance # ?
```